# Where Hyperledger fabric v1.1.0 endorsement-policy is stored?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I used balance-transfer of fabric-samples, and I confirmed blocks.
endorsement-policy wasn't in the block.

Where is Endorsement policy stored?
Also, once endorsment-policy is instantiated, is it possible to tamper/change the policy?
(I using Hyperledger Fabric v1.1.0-preview)

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know exactly where is the Endorsement Policy stored. May be someone from HLF TSC would help you here. But I know for sure that it is in no form which can be tampered with.
2. But **it is possible to change the endorsement policy of an already instantiated
   chaincode**. Please refer to this link for a CLI based example  [Fabric Documentation v1.1 : section Upgrade & Invoke](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channel_update.html?highlight=upgrade#upgrade-invoke).
3. In addition to that, if I remember correctly, it can be done from the Java SDK as well. We used to specify a different
   endorsement policy yaml and change the version of the chaincode and
   used to install and instantiate. [ You need to change the version,
   so you have to install another copy even if there is no binary
   change :( ]
4. As all the SDKs follow the same spec, NodeJS's upgrade API should
   also support this.

Comment: I know I can change endorsement-policy using api. Can malicious user do falsification ?